# How to fix exception handling issue in switch case statement?

Tags: java, exception

I am working on project for class, where we were tasked to design a calculator program with a menu containing 5 options. I am facing an issue when I am trying to code to catch if the user inputs a choice that is not between 1 and 5. Currently if the user inputs a number between 6 to 9. The exception will be caught the first time and an error message which says to enter a choice between 1 and 5 will be displayed and a message to re enter will appear. However if the user continues to enter a number between 6 to 9, the error message is not displayed and the main menu appears.  I am also trying to catch when a string is entered as input instead of a choice between 1 and 5 and display a different error message saying the user has entered an invalid input and then ask the user to re enter, however when a string is entered as the choice I get an input mismatch exception error but when a string is entered instead of a float after the operation has been chosen, then the correct error message is displayed.

I am a beginner to Java and am open to all suggestions but if it is possible I would like to keep my code somewhat similar to way it is written currently.

```
static void promptEnterKey() {
    System.out.println("Press enter key to continue ...");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.nextLine();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float Firstnum, Secondnum, Solution;
    int choice;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.printf("Welcome to Paul's Handy Calculator\n\n (1) Addition\n "
                + "(2) Subtraction\n (3) Multiplication\n (4) Division\n (5) Exit\n\n");
        System.out.printf("What would you like to do? ");
        choice = scan.nextInt();
        try {
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
                System.out.printf("You have not entered a number between 1 and 5. "
                        + "Try again.\n");
                System.out.printf("Enter your choice between 1 and 5 only: \n");
                choice = scan.nextInt();
                continue;
            }
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Please enter two floats to add, "
                        + "separated by a space: ");
                Firstnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Secondnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Solution = Firstnum + Secondnum;
                System.out.println("Result of adding " + Firstnum + " and " 
                        + Secondnum + " is " + Solution + "\n");
                promptEnterKey();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Please enter two floats to subtract, "
                        + "separated by a space: ");
                Firstnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Secondnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Solution = Firstnum - Secondnum;
                System.out.println("Result of subtracting " + Firstnum 
                        + " and " + Secondnum + " is " + Solution + "\n");
                promptEnterKey();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("Please enter two floats to multiply, "
                        + "separated by a space: ");
                Firstnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Secondnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Solution = Firstnum * Secondnum;
                System.out.print("Result of multiplying " + Firstnum + " and " 
                        + Secondnum + " is " + Solution + "\n");
                promptEnterKey();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Please enter two floats to divide, "
                        + "separated by a space: ");
                Firstnum = scan.nextFloat();
                Secondnum = scan.nextFloat();
                if (Secondnum == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You cannot divide by zero, "
                            + "please enter another number to divide by");
                    Secondnum = scan.nextFloat();
                }
                Solution = Firstnum / Secondnum;
                System.out.println("Result of dividing " + Firstnum + " and " 
                        + Secondnum + " is " + Solution + "\n");
                promptEnterKey();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Thank You for using Paul's Handy Calculator");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Try again.  ");
            String flush =scan.next();
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you declared choice as a char instead of an int?

Comment: To start, it would be a lot simpler if you moved your case bodies to methods.

Comment: I converted char to int and that solved the exception problem. Thanks @KMan

Comment: Even after i converted choice variable to an int, the second time a number greater than 1 to 5 is inputted the menu is displayed instead of the error message, and now an input mismatch exception error happens when a string is inputted. How would i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your welcome message outside of the do-while, move your initial `scan.nextInt()` call inside the try block, and remove your `scan.nextInt()` call inside your if statement:

```
// Moved welcome message outside of do-while
System.out.printf("Welcome to Paul's Handy Calculator\n\n (1) Addition\n "
        + "(2) Subtraction\n (3) Multiplication\n (4) Division\n (5) Exit\n\n");
System.out.printf("What would you like to do? ");

do {
    try {
        // Moved scan.nextInt inside of try block
        choice = scan.nextInt();
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
            System.out.printf("You have not entered a number between 1 and 5. " + "Try again.\n");
            System.out.printf("Enter your choice between 1 and 5 only: \n");          
            // Removed nextInt call
            continue;
        }
        ...
```